# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:535 throw e; ^ Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not def

Tags: express

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:535
throw e;
^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\reshn\OneDrive\Desktop\Chat\client\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:358:9)
at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:668:3)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:529:36)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:31)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
e-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1

while npm start node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:535
throw e;
^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\reshn\OneDrive\Desktop\Chat\client\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:358:9)
at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:668:3)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:529:36)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:31)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
e-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1